# Theron-Lite Theme - How to widen page width

Tags: css, wordpress, width, margins

So I'm using WordPress to develop my website. The theme I am using is 'Theron-Lite'. I have created a child theme with a custom style.css

The pages look great, I just want them slightly wider. I don't need to make it the entire length of the screen; just maybe an extra 5%.

I can't figure out how to do this. The closest I've come to modify the page width is by adding this code into my style.css:

/*PAGE WIDTH*/

## content .single_wrap{width:105%!important;}

By changing {width:100%!important;} to {width:105%!important;}, it changes the page to the desired width. However! It's not centered. The change extends the page on the right-hand side instead of the left and the right equally.

Here's an example: http://paradigmcurve.com/?page_id=65

Is there a way to extend the page on both sides, equally? Or does the issue lie in the margins?

Hopefully there are some savvy developers out there that can help me out.
Thanks for any consideration!

Answer (score 0):

you have a .center class width a fixed with of 1000px, how about you change the width of this ?

Comment: Wow. You are a genius! Thank you so much!

One quick follow-up: any way to get rid of those grey bars next to the top Navigation Menu? I'm assuming I have to extend the menu class somehow as well?

http://paradigmcurve.com/?page_id=65

Comment: yes, just delete the background image in "body #menu_wrap, #topmenu ul li ul li" and in "#menu_wrap"

Comment: Found an alternative solution- I simply added this to the bottom of my child theme's stylesheet:

body #header #menu_wrap{background:none!important;}

... thank you all so much for taking the time to help me out! I greatly appreciate it.